# How to deserialize JSON text to BsonDocument with ISO 8601 formatted DateTime fields?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, bson

Given a JSON text that contains an ISO8601 formatted timestamp field, as below

```
{
  "Timestamp":"2016-01-29T14:51:52.4338035-06:00",
  "someKey": "someVal"
}
```

How can I create a BsonDocument that has properly typed fields?

I've tried

`BsonDocument bsonDocument = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(json);`

but then the Type of the value at `bsonDocument["Timestamp"]` is `BsonString` and not `BsonDateTime`.

If I try to call `bsonDocument["Timestamp"].AsBsonDateTime`, it throws an `InvalidCastException`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Use `BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDateTime>(json)`